# Find area lies inside cardioid $r = 1 + \cos θ$ and outside circle $r = \cos θ$

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

> What is the area of the region that lies inside the cardioid $r = 1 + \cos( θ)$ and outside the circle $r = \cos (θ)$?

The graph for this problem is

[image]

In attempting to solve this problem, I reasoned that the area inside the cardioid but outside the circle is the area of the cardioid minus the area of the circle. This gave me the setup: $$\frac12\left(\int^{2\pi}_{0}\left(1+\cos(\theta)\right)^2-\cos^2(\theta)\ d\theta\right)\\=\frac12\left(\int^{2\pi}_{0}1+2\cos(\theta)+\cos^2(\theta)-\cos^2(\theta)\ d\theta\right)\\=\frac12\left(\int^{2\pi}_{0}1+2\cos(2\theta)\ d\theta\right)\\=\frac12\left(\theta+\sin(2\theta)\right)|^{2\pi}_0\\=\pi$$
Why doesn't this method work? Is there something wrong with my calculation or is it my logic that is not holding true?

**EDIT:**
As I've been working more, I see that this kind of method does not seem to work for this problem either:

> What is the area of the region that lies outside the circle $r = \cos θ$ and inside the circle $r = 2 \cos θ$?

I do not seem to be able to simply subtract the area of the second circle from the area of the first. What is wrong with this method? Looking at the graphs it seems like this would work?

Comment: Note that you know the area of the enclosed circle (from elementary school), so just calculate the area inside the cardiod and subtract...

Comment: This method doesn't work because the curves are not "simultaneous", which is a common misunderstanding with polar curves since there is no analog in rectangular coordinates. The cardioid takes a full $2\pi$ to trace itself out, but the circle takes only half that time. You cannot integrate them together.

Comment: @NinadMunshi - If I'm understanding correctly, this means I cannot combine two integrals together with the same limits of integration in the polar system?

Comment: You can, but these do not have the same limits. Spend some time, draw a table and graph points one by one.

Comment: @NinadMunshi - I don't understand...

Comment: Spend the time to write a table, $r$ on one side, $\theta$ on the other, and slowly plot points for both curves from $\theta = 0$ on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the integral limits for the circle is $[-\frac\pi2, \frac\pi2]$. Thus, the integral should be set up as

$$\frac12\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}\left(1+\cos\theta\right)^2d\theta 
-\frac12\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2}\cos^2\theta\ d\theta = \frac{5\pi}4$$

Comment: Can you explain how you got those limits?

Comment: @Burt - Note that the circle starts at $(r,\theta)=(1,0)$ and ends the upper half-circle at $(0,\frac\pi2)$. Similarly, the lower-half is from $(1,0)$ to $(0,-\frac\pi2)$.

Comment: Isn't this the same as saying $0$ to $2\pi$? Why the need to start them in different spots?

Comment: @Burt - it is the same as $(0,\pi)$. The starting spot is not important, just preference.

Comment: So what was wrong with my method?

Comment: @Burt - your limits for the circle are $(0,2\pi)$ instead of  $(0,\pi)$.  you integrated the circle areas twice.